# So bootstrap is separating my buttons?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

My issue with this code is that when I added the links around the buttons it separated the buttons up. And instead of them all being joined they no longer are joined.

```
 <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <a href="/learn/popular-tags/all"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default <? if ($type == 'all'){ ?>active<? } ?>">All</button></a>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <a href="/learn/popular-tags/male"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default <? if ($type == 'male'){ ?>active<? } ?>">Male</button></a>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <a href="/learn/popular-tags/female"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default <? if ($type == 'female'){ ?>active<? } ?>">Female</button></a>
  </div>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <a href="/learn/popular-tags/couples"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default <? if ($type == 'couples'){ ?>active<? } ?>">Couples</button></a>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <a href="/learn/popular-tags/trans"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default <? if ($type == 'trans'){ ?>active<? } ?>">Trans</button></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Appreciate any help

Comment: Works fine here http://www.bootply.com/BfbxU2EoYg. If you have other CSS you should post that. Please make sure you have a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: @j08691 thankyou for the example that's the perfect example of it not working aha xD basically do you see how they do not join up? they curve in the middle of two buttons they should be flush together. if you take out the links for two you will see how they are meant to look

Comment: Are you referring to the rounded corners? If I remove the links that's the only difference I notice.

Comment: @C0dekid.php if you write that as an answer I will be sure to make that as solved. Thankyou very much.

Comment: @Lewis have put it in the answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of putting the button in a `a href` code you can do this:

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" class="btn btn-default">Click here</a>
```

The link will look like a button instead.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `button` element and move the classes over to the `a` element

```
  ...
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <a class="btn btn-default <? if ($type == 'all'){ ?>active<? } ?>" href="/learn/popular-tags/all">All</a>
  </div>
  ...
```

Bootply - http://www.bootply.com/IcLAD63W9u